# Youtube uploader from website

Tags: php, forms, input, youtube-api

I want users to upload videos directly to my youtube account, with their own titles and descriptions.

```
$youtube_video_title = "deltager"; // This is the uploading video title.
$youtube_video_description = "Example"; // This is the uploading video description.
$youtube_video_category = "News"; // This is the uploading video category.
$youtube_video_keywords = "example, video"; // This is the uploading video keywords.
```

This is the titles defined, and the next is the form.

```
 <form action="<?php echo($response->url); ?>?nexturl=<?php echo(urlencode($nexturl)); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkForFile();">
    Deltager Nr: <input type="text" name="deltager" />
    Emne: <input type="text" name="emne" />
  <input id="file" type="file" name="file"/>
  <div id="errMsg" style="display:none;color:red">
    You need to specify a file.
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo($response->token); ?>"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Film :-)" />

</form>
```

I want the input in the form, to be defined in the title and description etc.
So the "deltager", "example" and so on is changes to get the input-text.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what your question is?

Comment: When the user upload a video, and write "TEST" as a title in the inputfield, it should automaticly name the file "TEST".
Now all the files being uploaded is just called "Deltager" as a title, cause I don't somehow GET the text written in input-field.
Which I want. The file should be named whatever the user writes in the inputfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation you're going to have to do this in two steps, first accept the input from the user describing the video, then use the snippet you have above.

So:

1. Create a form with title, category, description, keywords etc.
2. Call the YouTube API with your XML request to retrieve the upload token
3. Use the upload token in the form above

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Browser_based_uploading

Comment: Everything works fine, and i got all this (i tihnk) but it's the name of the file, that just gets defined as what i've written in the $youtube_video_title = "deltager"; 

so all videos have a title called "deltager"..
even though I write "test" in the inputfield.

Comment: No, because this requires 2 request to achieve. One form which is submitted to your webserver which contains the title entered by your user, which you then submit to YouTube in the `GetUploadToken` request, then you need present the user with the 2nd form which is the one uploading the video file to YouTube.

Comment: ok. will try and look into it. thanks..
at least the user can upload videos.

Comment: When looking at it i'm not sure how you call the API with the XML to retrieve the upload token.
I looked at the link, but it just confuses me.
I've used this guys code and then of course added a input field for the title. (http://rubensargsyan.com/generate-youtube-video-browser-based-uploading-form-by-php/)